# Debugging a ReSharper plugin in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I'm trying to create a simple resharper (5.1) plugin, and I managed to add the correct references (which change names every version for some reason), and create a simple IActionHandler and Actions.xml. Everything appears to work if I drop the plugin dll into the ReSharper\v5.1\Bin\Plugins directory and start VS2010 (No warning/error messages). However, when I try to debug the plugin using devenv.exe as an external program and

/Resharper.Plugin "C:\MyPlugin\bin\Debug\MyPlugin.dll"

I get a warning when visual studio starts that says that no handler was found for MyNameSpace.MyAction. What could cause this problem?

Also: what is the simplest thing I can do in my plugin to test that my action is called? Can I show a message box or something? And how can I find the names of the various menus I can add actions to in ReSharper? If possible I'd like to add an item to the creation menu (where equality methods etc. can be created).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the identifier you provided in `Actions.xml` for the action doesn't match the identifier that you've decorated the action with (or the naming convention of the action).

A simplest test would be something like showing a MessageBox. As for the locations where the item can be added, unfortunately you won't be able to add it to the Generate menu - this menu is auto-populated from the various generator providers as described [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Generator+Items).

Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: But the plugin loads if I don't use the debugger, with the same dll. So I assume the action must be wired correctly!

Comment: Can I take a look at your solution? You can e-mail it to dn at jetbrains dot com.

Comment: Sure, I will have to separate it from a larger project, but I'lll find the time sometime closer to the weekend. Thanks!

Comment: Dmitri now it magically works (after first not working neither in normal or debug). This is something other than a difference between using the debugger or not. I'll let you know if I find something

Comment: Great! Keep in mind that plenty of things can lead to things not working. One of the most common if you accidentally kept any of the R# references as `Copy Local = true`. Seeing how you're not using the SDK, you might want to check that.

Comment: Yes I noticed that. Could copy local lead to a "handler of action X could not be found"?

Comment: Copy local = true can lead to lots of bad effects. You *must* ensure that your output folder doesn't have any R# assemblies. If it does, things will definitely go wrong.